# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error from stringbuilder within a while loop

Tags: java

The assignment is to, for example, remove char '`a`' from the String "`I am Sam am I Sam`", this is a bit code I have so far:

```
public String removeLetters() {
    String cleaned=sentence;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(cleaned);

    while(cleaned.indexOf(lookFor) != -1) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(cleaned.indexOf(lookFor));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This method returns fine when there's no while loop (though it only removes one char), but when I run it with the while loop I get the `OutOfBounds` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
while(cleaned.indexOf(lookFor) != -1) {
    builder.deleteCharAt(cleaned.indexOf(lookFor));
}
```

with this:

```
while(builder.indexOf(Character.toString(lookFor)) != -1) {
    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.indexOf(Character.toString(lookFor)));
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks for that, now onto trying to understand why, but that's for another day.  Thanks again!  Edit: turns out I just didn't know what the Character class was.

Comment: You must have already done that, but anyway just be sure to notice that I changed your `cleaned` references for `builder`, as other members mentioned. `Character.toString()` is just an utility method for converting a character (which is considered a numeric value in Java) into a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do this using [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method:

```
String cleaned = "I am Sam am I Sam";
cleaned = cleaned.replace("a", "");
System.out.println(cleaned);   // I m Sm m I Sm
```

Comment: I think you should use replaceall instead of replace.OP wants to change the all of a

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş `replace` replaces all the occurrences only. `replaceAll` is for regex replacement. That's the only difference.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my wrong knowledge :) I have already upvoted :)

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş No issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the `while` loop is the index in the `cleaned` `StringBuilder`, but then you're using **the same index** to delete characters from `builder` - after the first character has been deleted, they no longer match.

In short:

```
public String removeLetters() {
    String cleaned=sentence;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(cleaned);

    while(builder.indexOf(lookFor) != -1) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.indexOf(lookFor));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
cleaned.replaceAll(lookFor,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to remove from the builder, not the source string.  Also, you initially had an infinite loop, attempting to modify the builder string, but only checking the source string, which wouldn't change.  This compiled and ran fine:

```
public String removeLetters()
{
    String lookFor = "a";
    String original="I am Sam am I Sam";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(original);
    while(builder.indexOf(lookFor) != -1) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.indexOf(lookFor));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```